# sql server insert missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Table A**

```
empid   tdate     transcode
1       2006-01-1     HI
1       2008-01-1     PR
1       2008-11-30    TE
1       2009-01-02    RH
2       2007-01-1     HI
2       2009-01-1     PR
2       2011-11-30    TE
```

I am trying to do this in SQL Server 2008, basically I want to fill the missing `tdate` as show below, however if RH tdate is greater than TE tdate than include missing tdate upto current year as in 2013 for each employee else stop at TE tdate. Thank for the help

Final Results

**Table A**

```
empid   tdate     transcode
1       2006-01-1     HI
1       2007-01-1     HI
1       2008-01-1     PR
1       2008-11-30    TE
1       2009-01-02    RH
1       2010-01-02    RH
1       2011-01-02    RH
1       2012-01-02    RH
1       2013-01-02    RH
2       2007-01-1     HI
2       2008-01-1     HI
2       2009-01-1     PR
2       2010-01-1     PR
2       2011-11-30    TE
```

I started but I'm stuck, not sure if I am on the right path.

```
select t.empid, t.tdate,t.transcode
from table1 t 
inner join table2 t2  on t.empid = t2.empid and t.tdate < t2.tdate 
order by t.transcode desc
```

Here are the queries one can use to make my table quickly and run queries on it -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableDates](
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [tdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [transcode] [varchar](2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000973C00000000 AS DateTime), N'HI')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x00009A1600000000 AS DateTime), N'PR')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x00009B6400000000 AS DateTime), N'TE')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x00009B8500000000 AS DateTime), N'RH')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x000098A900000000 AS DateTime), N'HI')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x00009B8400000000 AS DateTime), N'PR')
INSERT [dbo].[TableDates] ([empid], [tdate], [transcode]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x00009FAB00000000 AS DateTime), N'TE')
```

Comment: What do you mean by missing date?

Comment: select t.empid, t.tdate,t.transcode
 from table1 t 
inner join table2 t2  on t.empid = t2.empid 
 and t.tdate < t2.tdate 
    order by t.transcode desc --so far i am stuck

Comment: missing date meaning filling the date gap e.g there is data for 2006 and 2008 but none for 2007 so i want to include 2007

Comment: Please put your query in your post, and we'll need to see sample data from both tables you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to insert rows with a trans code of `'RH'` for combinations of employee id and date that are not in the table.

The following query does this:

```
insert into TableDates(empid, tdate, transcode)
    select etd.empid, etd.tdate, 'RH' as transcode
    from (select e.empid, td.tdate
          from (select distinct empid from TableDates) e cross join
               (select distinct tdate from TableDates) td
         ) etd left outer join
         TableDates td
         on td.empid = etd.empid and td.tdate = etd.tdate
    where td.empid is null;
```

You can see this work on [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeda9/1) SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Not sure if it will do what the OP wants. Ran your query on my table & then, SELECT [empid],[tdate],[transcode]
[TableDates]
order by empid, transcode . ResultSet - 
empid tdate transcode
1 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 HI
1 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 PR
1 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 RH
1 2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 RH
1 2011-11-30 00:00:00.000 RH
1 2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 RH
1 2008-11-30 00:00:00.000 TE
2 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 HI
2 2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 PR
2 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 RH
2 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 RH
2 2008-11-30 00:00:00.000 RH
2 2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 RH
2 2011-11-30 00:00:00.000 TE

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, however what if the RH is greater than TE how do I include from the last RH tdate to current date.